# PyCharm says package isn't included in project requirements but it is

Tags: python, pycharm

What is PyCharm not seeing that it wants to be seeing?  In my Python file, PyCharm is indicating its annoyance and when I hover it tells me this:

[image]

but my requirements.txt contains this:

```
ftd2xx==1.1.2 \
    --hash=sha256:6af0593065816e937db428db3dc66c51f348be7f998f862fa213e59d3754eb4e \
    --hash=sha256:953d90e02e0070111a6dae64e70e82ce79c071b6fd96552b72adb6dabc8a288e \
    --hash=sha256:f920875702ef5478e97be442877d6ccfec211dff12cff56cf97ad122096d40a1
```

What is PyCharm looking for that I haven't given it?

Comment: When you choose the "Add imported packages to requirements..." option, what happens, our of curiosity? I will say, though, that there appear to be a lot of results for googling "package containing module is not listed in the project requirements", so I think looking through all those results could help out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be that it's a [PyCharm bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11963), and has been since 2014, and they don't seem terribly interested in fixing it.